# How to get started analyzing audio signals for detecting cracks in a material?

Tags: audio

I have two processes, one is normal and the other with some cracks of material. And I have the acoustic signals got from the materials by a sensor. I want to compare these signals to see if this signal can be used to detect cracks. I think two different processes (with and without cracks) will create two different signals. Based on that, I want to compare these signals, but I'm new to DSP.

Could you please give me some suggestions what I should do, step by step to process these signals?

(I will of course read books to get knowledge about DSP, but it's really huge. I therefore hope that someone can tell me what I should do, step by step to process those signals. By doing so, I can save some time)

Comment: What are you hoping to learn from the comparison?

Comment: What do you mean "I have non-stationary audio signals from 2 different processes" precisely? I did not understand what did you mean by 'process'.

Comment: I have two processes, one is normal and the other with some cracks of material. And I have the acoustic signals got from the materials by a sensor. 
I want to compare these signals to see if this signal can be used to detect cracks.
I have read somethings about DSP but it's really huge and it's not my major. I therefore hope that someone can give me some suggestions what I should do, what I should read.
It seems to be a stupid question, but I hope I can make it faster with your help.
Thank you.

Comment: So, you measured two audio signal from materials. Then, you have a 'normal' signal which can be thought as ground truth. And you have an 'abnormal' signal which characterizes cracks or other problems in material. You want to detect crack material by audio signal by using 'normal' signal. Am I right so far?

Comment: @Deniz: yeah, that's what I intended to do. I think two different processes (with and without cracks) will create two different signals. Based on that, I want to compare these signals.

Comment: If I were you, I would first look at the STFT of these signals. You can control the differences in a spectrogram (See Matlab's spectrogram function). Unfortunately, I do not know any 'direct measure' for comparison two nonstationary signals, but I guess there is no 'unique' and 'universal' measure which is valid for every type of audio signals.

Comment: @John I updated your question with some of the detail you provided in the comments. It would be helpful to provide some information about how the signals were generated (e.g. Is this from machinery that's already vibrating, or did you have to hit it with a hammer to generate the signal?).

Comment: @datageist and Deniz:  the materials are already vibrating. One material was broken because of its poor structure, or because of stronger vibration, or both reasons.  I just focus on how to distinguish the signals from broken and non-broken materials. Thank you.

Comment: If you can do, I suggest you to compute spectrograms and add them to your question. Then, we may suggest a specific algorithm for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a programming question!

In any case if you need to read books to understand DSP and are trying to compare two non stationary processes I suggest you start reading right away because most steps I tell you won't make sense and you need to answer a host of questions even before anyone can answer this question.

Signal processing deals with lot of statistical phenomena and you have to work with it emperically many a times. Not to say there are no fixed rules but the step-by-step to process this signals is hard enough when data is stationary. Given that you have non stationary data, get reading and once you have a hang of it ask some pointed questions on dsp.stackexchange.com